# Is the product of two indecomposable continua indecomposable?

Tags: general-topology

We say $X$ is a *continuum*, if it is a compact, connected metric space. A subset $A\subseteq X$ is said to be a *subcontinuum* is $A$ is a continuum. A continuum $X$ is said to be *decomposable* if $X=A\cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are proper subcontinuum of $X$, and $X$ is *indecomposable* is it is not *decomposable*.

I claim that $X\times Y$ is indecomposable for two indecomposable continua $X$ and $Y$. I proceed in following way: If possible let us assume that it is decomposable, i.e. $X\times Y=A\cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are proper subcontinua of the product. Consider the projections $\pi_x : X\times Y\rightarrow X$ and $\pi_y:X\times Y\rightarrow Y$.

Here, $\pi_x(A),\, \pi_x(B)$ are subcontinua of $X$ and we have $\pi_x(A)\cup \pi_x(B)=X$. Since $X$ is indecomposable so we have either $\pi_x(A)=X$ or $\pi_x(B)=X$. Similarly, either $\pi_y(A)=Y$ or $\pi_y(B)=Y$.

Now i am lost here and can't really think how to move forward. Can anyone please help me to proceed hereafter if i am correct? Any hint will be appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: I started writing an answer but then I realized it's late and I'm tired. For a hint, it's too coarse to look at projections of the entire subsets onto $X$ and $Y$. Try finding an $x\in X$ such that $A\cap (\{x\}\times Y)\neq \{x\}\times Y$ and is nonempty (one may not exist, this has to be treated as a separate case).